# Condicional para mostrar otro valor en JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi consulta es la siguientes me gustaria valida un campo y si es correcto mostrar otro dato en otro campo.

```
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                                    <label style="font-size:90%;" class="text-muted" for="">RUC:</label>
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                              <input id="txtNumRUCModal" name="numRucPIS" type="number" min="1" max="999999999999" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
                                         </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12">
                                   <hr class="sep">
                                   <i onclick="validarRuc();" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:pointer"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">                            
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <hr class="sep">
                                       <input id="txtRazonSModal" name="razSocPis" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven en la imagen lo que necesito es que se valide que ese numero en el campo ruc sea correcto y si esta bien entonces en el otro input debe mostrar un valor digamos "San Luis". Agradeceria la ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Date una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio y por la sección [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. Tengo restricciones en mi red y no puedo ver la imagen que posteas,por favor incluye el código.

Comment: añadi el codigo estimado, espero se me pueda entener lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

En tu función validarRuc()

deberás tomar el valor del txtNumRUCModal y después con un simple if validar contra el valor que deseas, 
con javascript

```
function validarRuc(){
    if(document.getElementById('txtNumRUCModal').value == "42342323523"){

        document.getElementById('txtRazonSModal').value = 'tu razon social';
    }
}
```

o con jquery

```
    function validarRuc(){
    if($("#txtNumRUCModal").val() == "42342323523"){

        $("#txtRazonSModal").val('tu razon social');
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio!

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre algo así

```js
    function validarRuc(){
        var txtNumRUCModal = document.getElementById("txtNumRUCModal").value;
        if( txtNumRUCModal  == "1"){
           document.getElementById("txtRazonSModal").value = 'My value';
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <label style="font-size:90%;" class="text-muted" for="">RUC:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="txtNumRUCModal" name="numRucPIS" type="number" min="1" max="999999999999" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12">
    <hr class="sep">
    <i onclick="validarRuc();" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:pointer"></i>
    <button onclick="validarRuc();"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <hr class="sep">
        <input id="txtRazonSModal" name="razSocPis" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio!